# PHP - Looking into Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, phar

I would like to understand better how `Composer` works and I would like to follow its code execution after I lauch a console command.

If I edit the code of `composer.phar` I broke its signature and it doesn't work anymore.

Is there an alternative way to install/use/launch composer, so I could debug what it is actually doing?

Comment: Did you try to get just source  `git clone https://github.com/composer/composer.git` and than play with it?

Comment: Yes, can I just use `bin/composer` then to launch composer?

Comment: composer is widely used and pretty much a standard in certain PHP scenarios (Symfony). I wouldn't suppose it's bugged unless you really know what you are doing. Options are, you've probably used it wrong. For example, did you take a good look at [semver](http://semver.org)?

Comment: @pid I'm not looking for a bug in composer, just trying to understand how it works

Comment: Yes, use `bin/composer` to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Composer has a "debugger" in the form of the [diagnose](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#diagnose) console command but its output is really a checklist of things that Composer needs to work rather than a list of things Composer does. That said, if you really want to know how a specific command works:

1. Run the command
2. Look at the output
3. Follow [the source code](https://github.com/composer/composer/tree/master/src/Composer) starting with the source for the [Composer console application](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Console/Application.php) and figure out how that output was generated.

And if you want to know what the Composer autoloader is doing when you run your PHP app:

1. Hook up a debugger like [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) or use a tool like [Blackfire.io](https://blackfire.io/) to trace what methods Composer is calling.
2. Read [the source code](https://github.com/composer/composer/tree/master/src/Composer/Autoload) for Composer's Autoloader to figure out what those methods are doing.

Just note that running Composer with a debugger attached [reduces speed considerably](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#xdebug-impact-on-composer).